# C#, open excel file and apply a filter to retrive specific rows?

Tags: c#, excel, autofilter

issue :
my code always return one row instead of 13.

Code:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
Excel.Range xlrange = null;

string sCurrentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

xlApp = new Excel.Application();

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sCurrentDir + @"\Res\res.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

xlrange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;       
xlrange.AutoFilter(5, "4", Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);

Excel.Range filteredRange = xlrange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,    Excel.XlSpecialCellsValue.xlTextValues);

MessageBox.Show(filteredRange.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

---

as you can see i want to Filter Column 5 With Value "4". it should returns 13 Rows but it always returns 1 row.

any help will appreciated

Comment: How many rows are you expecting? If you make the Excel application visible does the filtering look to have done what you expected?

Comment: On a side note, the way you are setting `xlWorkBook` (and other variables) is likely to cause you an issue. See https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/category/technical/com-interop/ (search for `Fear the Period`).

Comment: @mjwills hi, thank you for your reply. see the update please. i checked your link but it didn't help me.

Comment: @mjwills how to make Excel application visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question:

```
...
...
Excel.Range filteredRange = xlrange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,    Excel.XlSpecialCellsValue.xlTextValues);

for (int areaId = 1; areaId <= filteredRange.Areas.Count; areaId++)
{
    areaRange = filteredRange.Areas[areaId];
    object[,] areaValues = areaRange.Value;
    for (int row = 0; row < areaValues.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        // ignore the Header row
        if (areaValues[row + 1, 1].ToString().ToLower() == "id") continue;

        //Add The Row To A List Or Array

     }
}
```

Comment: What is areaRange  ?

Answer (score 3):

if you use
`xlApp.Visible = true;`
you can make the Excel application visible

I just ran your code and it seems to work as expected for my sample sheet

My sample Sheet

[image]

After I run your code, I see the filter being applied properly

[image]

[image]

Since you get 1 row it seems that the filter is not matching any rows and the row count of 1 may mean just the header row.

Few items to note are:

(1) The 5th Column is Column E (not Column F) i.e., Column A is the first column

(2) Cross check your data by manually adding the filter

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes by making xlApp visible filter works fine BUT All i need is to access the filtered data in the code. actually i need to access every single one of the rows that filtered by code. the #5 column is ok and it should returns 13 rows

Answer (score 1):

set  autoFilterCells.AutoFilter = true;

```
 using (ExcelRange autoFilterCells = ws.Cells[
    startRowIndex, territoryNameIndex,
    toRowIndex, totalIndex])
{
    autoFilterCells.AutoFilter = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do the following, I tested it is working.

```
Excel.Range filteredRange = xlrange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Excel.XlSpecialCellsValue.xlTextValues);

int areaId; 
int filteredRow;
areaId = filteredRange.Areas.Count;
filteredRow = areaId - 1; //Skipping the header row
MessageBox.Show(filteredRow.ToString());
```